# split a string in javascript based on start and end delimiters

Tags: javascript, sorting

I'm looking for a way in Javascript to split a string into an array based on "starting" and "ending" separators rather than one separator, as str.split currently does.

For example, if I have this string:

```
const str = '{lang}_{cmp_abbrev}_{cmp_type}_{pl_abbrev}_{w}x{h}_d{dv}c{cv}'
```

The result of:

```
str.mySplit('{', '}');
```

would be this:

```
[
    '{lang}',
    '_',
    '{cmp_abbrev}',
    '_',
    '{cmp_type}',
    '_',
    '{pl_abbrev}',
    '_',
    '{w}',
    'x',
    '{h}',
    '_d',
    '{dv}',
    'c',
    '{cv}'
]
```

Thus, it would take into consideration 2 characters instead of one character when determining how the string split should occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex to the rescue!

```js
const str = '{lang}_{cmp_abbrev}_{cmp_type}_{pl_abbrev}_{w}x{h}_d{dv}c{cv}'
const values = [...str.matchAll(/\w+|\{\w+\}/g)].flat()

console.log(values)
```

Comment: This seems to be omitting some values. It seems to give this instead of the desired result:

[
  "lang",
  "cmp_abbrev",
  "cmp_type",
  "pl_abbrev",
  "w",
  "h",
  "dv",
  "cv"
] (although, I think that your answer is very close!)

Comment: I don't see which value has been omitted.

Comment: The underscore values, as well as "x" and "_d" and "c"

Comment: Ok, now I understand, updated the question

Answer (score 0):

`Array#split` can take regular expressions with capturing groups:

```
'foo{bar}baz{}!'.split(/(\{.*?\})/g)
//=> ['foo', '{bar}', 'baz', '{}', '!']
```

Just be aware that empty strings can be generated e.g.,

```
'{foo}bar{baz}'.split(/(\{.*?\})/g)
//=> ['', '{foo}', 'bar', '{baz}', '']

'{foo}{bar}{baz}'.split(/(\{.*?\})/g)
//=> ['', '{foo}', '', '{bar}', '', '{baz}', '']
```

But that is both normal and to be expected. If these are undesirable you can filter them out:

```
'{foo}{bar}{baz}'.split(/(\{.*?\})/g).filter(Boolean)
//=> ['{foo}', '{bar}', '{baz}']
```

---

With your initial string we have:

```
'{lang}_{cmp_abbrev}_{cmp_type}_{pl_abbrev}_{w}x{h}_d{dv}c{cv}'.split(/(\{.*?\})/g).filter(Boolean)
//=> ['{lang}', '_', '{cmp_abbrev}', '_', '{cmp_type}', '_', '{pl_abbrev}', '_', '{w}', 'x', '{h}', '_d', '{dv}', 'c', '{cv}']
```

Answer (score 0):

If your example string always have that format, you could use split and capture 1 or more word characters in a group to keep in the result after the split.

Then assert a closing curly to the left, and opening curly to the right:

```
(?<=})(\w+)(?={)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7rDzEF/1).

```js
const str = '{lang}_{cmp_abbrev}_{cmp_type}_{pl_abbrev}_{w}x{h}_d{dv}c{cv}'
const values = str.match(/{[^{}]*}|[^\s{}]+/g)
console.log(values)
```

Another option is to match from `{...}` or match 1+ non whitespace chars other than `{` and `}` using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated):

```
{[^{}]*}|[^\s{}]+
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZepvV2/1).

```js
const str = '{lang}_{cmp_abbrev}_{cmp_type}_{pl_abbrev}_{w}x{h}_d{dv}c{cv}'
const values = str.match(/{[^{}]*}|[^\s{}]+/g)
console.log(values)
```